# jQuery UI sortable - keep the divs one after another with different widths

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a problem - I want to use the jQuery UI sortable plugin on a list with different items widths, like 1 `li` that have 100% of the total width, and another that have 50% of the total width.
The problem starts when the elements have different heights - it's float one after another (as any normal element with `float` would do), but I want them not to have the spaces between the next items, like in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMOBS.jpg

I tied to find something about that - but all I've found is stuff about 2 columns linking, and it doesn't helps me because I can't use the 100% width element..

this is my sortable area: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncIk1.jpg

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just follow [the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid). Sortable + float = fun. Example here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wqehc/1/)

**edit**: Sorry Joe, I misunderstood your question. In order to create a grid of things with different heights you can't use `float`s. In fact there are very few ways you can layout things with different widths *and* heights. Doing it programatically like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) does is the only thing that comes to mind; as shown in [this demo](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/osFxj).